# ExtJS-- how to show array values vertically in grid tooltip (tdAttr)?

Tags: arrays, extjs

I have a grid column that displays total number of values. On mouseover of that column, I show an array of values like so: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7..... But i want to show the values vertically like:
1
2
3
4
5
6
..
..
..

for better legibility since these values can also be dates or long strings.

```
my Code:

  colRenderer: function(value, meta, record) {
    if(record.data["total"] <= 12){
      var vals = record.data["totalVals"];
      meta.tdAttr = 'data-hide="user" data-closable="true" data-qtip="<b>All Values: ' +        vals + '</b>"';
        return value;
    }
  }
```

What this code does is checks the Total column count and if its less than or equal to 12, a mouseover that column will show a tooltip containing the total vals from the totalVals array.

if i add for loop inside if condition i can print array values vertically:

```
for(i=0; i<totalVals.length; i++){
        document.write(totalVals[i] + "<br>");
}
```

I just need to know how to do that in the tooltip!

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your array in record field `totalVals` then you can try:

```
renderer:function(v, meta, record) {
    var qtip=record.get('totalVals').join('<br />');
    meta.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + Ext.String.htmlEncode(qtip) + '"';
    return v;
}
```